# Connect a global variable for a user preference

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

We display a currency using `react-intl`, such as:

```
<FormattedNumber value={132.4} style="currency" currency="GBP" />
```

I'm adjusting our system so that each user can configure their currency. When a user logs in we will pull the active currency from our API, for example "GBP". I can then connect each component to pull the active currency from the store:

```
@connect((store) => {
    return {
        activeCurrency: store.user.preferences.currency
    }
})
export default class ExamplePage extends React.Component {

    render() {  
        return (
                <div class="row">
                    <FormattedNumber value={132.4} style="currency" currency={this.props.activeCurrency} />   
                </div>
            )
    }
}
```

This approach works fine. However, I will end up setting the `activeCurrency` property in all my `@connect` functions throughout my application. Is there a cleaner way to connect some sort of global variable which I can call anywhere in the React hierarchy to avoid this duplication?

Comment: I guess you could pass it as a prop from a parent component if you didn't need to connect some of the smaller components.

Comment: Yep. I guess that's kind of what I'm trying to avoid. I was hoping there would be a cleaner way instead of having to keep passing down the currency code through a tree of components. I can see myself having to decorate a lot of different components with the currency code.

Comment: yeah it sounds annoying. I am researching Higher-Order Components at the moment. perhaps they could be useful check [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html) or maybe you need something like a composition, you can read about that [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html). they are both more advanced techniques with react that are quite powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Pull the logic into its own reusable function:

```
// withCurrency.js: 
const withCurrency = connect((store) => {
    return {
        activeCurrency: store.user.preferences.currency
    }
});

export default withCurrency;
```

---

```
// ExamplePage.js
import withCurrency from './withCurrency.js';

@withCurrency
class ExamplePage extends React.Component {
    // ...
}

export default ExamplePage;
```